# javafx scenebuilder 1.1 inserts namespaces which cause parse errors

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

The latest javafx scenebuilder 1.1 inserts namespaces when I save my fxml file

```
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2"
```

When I open the file in the Netbeans 7.3.1 editor, I get errors like "Controller is not defined on root component". I delete the '1' to fix it.

and in the NetBeans IDE Retriever Pane:

> Aug 29, 2013 10:37:32 AM : Retrieving Location:
>   http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2
>
> Error: Unknown Host: javafx.com URL Resource

There is a controller. The problem is why it is creating

`xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"`

instead of

`xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"`?

Answer (score 2):

SB developers knew about this [bug](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-5834). At this moment I resolve it by download Netbeans Developer version. Also I install jdk-8. Resoult: any bugs. But yet little tested id.

Comment: Thanks for the information that it is a known bug https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/DTL-5834

Answer (score 1):

**1.)** When creating an application with SceneBuilder you most likely will not yet have a `controller` class in place which handles the events and everything else in your application. Saving the `*.fxml` file will give you something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0"
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
    <children>
    ...more here...
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

You need to create your application controller and add it the main node `<AnchorPane ...>` as the following shows (use full package path):

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" ... fx:controller="application.ListAndTableViewController">
```

**2.)** If you have a `controller` already, you can just specify it in SceneBuilder as shown in the attached picture.

[image: SceneBuilder]

By following one of the two approaches, Netbeans will not give you the error when opening your by the SceneBuilder created file.

Comment: No, that is not the problem - there is a controller. The problem is why it is creating `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" ` instead of `xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" `

Comment: Why it is doing that I cannot tell :( But I tested with NetBeans and after creating the JavaFX project and changed the FXML using SceneBuilder I ran in the problem. Even it was working and comiling in NetBeans, when hovering over the `fx:controller` it gave me the error you described before. SRY

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and have not found the answer.

Comment: @nyyrikki I did try your second option. In SceneBuilder, I see the controller listed. However, the version number is appended in the fxml file and opening in NB gives an error.